# Property DefaultLanguageName is not available Error on saving db settings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

When I open DB settings and try to change any setting it throws an error on save:

> Property DefaultLanguageName is not available for Database
>   '[TMS-API555]'. This property may not exist for this object, or may
>   not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

[image]

It really does show empty language setting

[image]

I tried to reset language via TSQL

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 2 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

> Configuration option 'default language' changed from 3 to 2. Run the
>   RECONFIGURE statement to install.

After that it still shows empty language and throws the error on save.

Tried

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::dbname TO [sa];
```

didn't work

Facts:

1. I updated SQL Server 2016 to latest available version 13.0.4474.0
2. Windows Server 2016
3. Management Studio 14.0.17199.0
4. Logged in as sysadmin
5. If I create a new empty DB - there is no error and everything works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a contained database, set the default language with `ALTER DATABASE`. For example:

```
ALTER DATABASE [TMS-API555] SET DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = english;
```

Comment: Hello, maybe you know I set the language on production DB, then make backup, restore on test server and have language setting not set again and have to update it?